# About request, controller

Tags: octobercms

I have this function in my controller. Not working, 0 result

```
public function onSearchVoyage() { $lieu_depart = (string)Input::get('lieudepart');

    $voyage = Db::table('olivier_ndaoo_voyage')
        ->where('lieudepart',  "$lieu_depart")
        ->get();

    return $voyage;
}
```

But if I do this it works

```
public function onSearchVoyage() { $lieu_depart = (string)Input::get('lieudepart');

    $voyage = Db::table('olivier_ndaoo_voyage')
        ->where('lieudepart',  "Paris")
        ->get();

    return $voyage;
}
```

What's the problem?

Answer (score 0):

Is `Input::get('lieudepart')` coming from a form? 
Is it coming from a query in URL like `example.com?lieudepart=Paris`?

If it is coming from a form are you sure that the input value has `name='lieudepart'`??

I would recommend returning `Input::get('lieudepart')` instead of the database record to figure out what your are getting from your input.